# Tab order issue in C# windows app

Tags: c#

I have a simple windows application in C#. I have set the tab order using the **View->Tab Order**.

A group box with two radio buttons has its tab index set to 0, followed by a group box with check boxes and some buttons.

When I run the application, the form loads up with the first radio button (tab index is 0.1) in the group box already checked. I have tried to set its checked property to false in the load procedure. No success. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`Tabindex` is of data type Int32 and for each control is inherited from `Control.TabIndex`,  try setting the 0.1 value to 1 or another integer value.

More Info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The "0.1" value appears in the WinForms Designer because it is a nested tab-order. The control's tab-index is actually `1` but its parent (a group-box) has a tab-index of `0`. If you have the groupbox nested within another control again (with index `2`) then the designer might show "`2.0.1.`", for example.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Express 2013 Community, the default checked property for the radio buttons is false. You can set up the checked property to a value you like.
If you want radioButton2 to be checked then change its checked property to true in the form load event.

Comment: I want the tab order to stay as I have set it for inputting data. My question is why does the radios button come up checked by default when form loads? I have tried to set its checked property to false in load procedure but no success. I don't want any default selections when form loads. Why this behavior in form load?